# How do I set up a local domain name in Apache and Ubuntu, eg website.sam?

Tags: configuration, apache2

I would like to map my directories/subdomains in the following way:

> /home/sam/sites/* to http://*.sam

I don't want to have to add a line to my hosts file every time I spool up a new site.

I'm a beginner when it comes to configuring and installing apache, what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Check out this apache doc: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html

Comment: you mean `http://localhost.sam` or `http://sam.localhost`?

Comment: Mapping a subdomain for `localhost` requires editing the `hosts` file.

Comment: Sam152 - have you been able to achieve what you wanted following the comments above?

Comment: @Mark, I have listed the steps it took me to get it working below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out there are quite a few steps involved in getting this working. Here is how I solved it:

1. Edit /etc/resolve.conf to set your domain name resolution to your local machine by commenting out any existing lines and adding `nameserver 127.0.0.1`. After this line add another line containing a secondary dns server for resolving other sites, eg `nameserver 8.8.8.8`. Some program also overwrites this file every time you boot, so you can use `chmod 0444 /etc/resolv.conf` to prevent this from happening (there might be a better way to achieve this).
2. Install dnsmasq, and at the end of /etc/dnsmasq.conf add a line `address=/your-custom-local-domain/127.0.0.1`
3. Create a new apache site config by placing a file called localdomain into 
   `/etc/apache2/sites-available` with the text at the bottom of this answer.
4. Run the following command `sudo a2ensite config localdomain`.
5. Reboot apache, and create a new folder in ~/ called Sites.

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName 127.0.0.1
>     ServerAlias *.your-custom-local-domain
>     VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%2/Sites/%1/
>     #ErrorLog /home/%2/logs/error.%1.log
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Now any new folder you create in the sites directory should be mapped to `foldername.your-custom-local-domain`.

Comment: Well done Sam!!

Comment: Thanks Mark, it took a while to figure out but was totally worth it for convenience sake.

Comment: This is ssssooooooooo much simpler than what we had been doing in the house. Thanks for sharing your solution!

Comment: how i can do this in WSL ? this not work in WSL

Comment: Still good for Ubuntu 22?