# Problems with permissions in apache Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.04, permissions, apache2, localhost

I have had some problems with setting up my localhost.
I have been following this guide --> [how-do-i-set-up-a-local-domain-name-in-apache-and-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52664/how-do-i-set-up-a-local-domain-name-in-apache-and-ubuntu-eg-website-sam/385563#385563)

But now I'm stuck my localhost only returns a 403 error so there is some problems with my permissions but i have no idea of what it should be..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards Peter

Comment: Please show relevant lines of /var/log/apache2/error.log or if you have set one in the vhost config the matching errorlog of your domain. Also: Do you get any errors when you restart apache2?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your webserver runs as the user www-data and that your site's document root is /var/www/blah.

Check that the www-data user has permissions to enter /var/www/blah with:

1. As root, run `su - www-data` then `cd /var/www/blah`. If this returns a permission denied error, your permissions to one of the directories in the path are set incorrectly. Fix with `chmod +x /var/....`.
2. Again, as root run: `date > /var/www/blah/date.txt; chmod +r /var/www/blah/date.txt`. Can you access http://yourdomain.com/date.txt ? If you can, your virtualhost is probably configured with directory indexing disabled and most likely it tries to find an index.html, index.htm, index.php, etc. and when it fails, it throws an HTTP/403.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

I can creat the file and chmod it but i still can't access it thru my browser, I've also tried to create an index.html with the same method with the same result

Comment: Were you able to enter the document root directory as the user that the webserver runs as (typically www-data)?

Comment: I think I was, sorry I'm not the most experienced ubnutu user (been at it for about 4 month) but I ran these commands in my terminal

su root
su - www-data

the whoami-command returned www-data
and when I cd into my sites folder (/home/username/Sites/pl) I'm not reciving any permissionerrors